# truncate integer left in c++ or generic example

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

Is there an alegant way to truncate integer in left direction decimal or base-independent?

For example I have:

```
unsigned int val1 = 17301;
```

The algorithm must by one call truncate 1 (decimal)digit from left so for val1 the result of 4 calls would be:

```
truncate_left(17301) returns 7301
truncate_left(7301) returns 301
truncate_left(301) returns 1
truncate_left(1) returns 0
```

The return value is integer also. The c/c++ solution is best for me. Any external (and/or) math libraries are not wellcome, I'm interested in generic way to do it

@ATaylor
my ugly solution was:

```
unsigned int truncate_left(unsigned int val) {
  unsigned int divider = 1000000000, dec;
  for(unsigned int pow10 = 10; pow10 > 0; pow10--) {
    if(val % divider != val) {
      dec = val / divider;
      printf("dec = %d\n", divider);
      break;
    }
    divider /= 10;
  }
  return val - dec * divider;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `c/c++ solution is best for me` Homework????

Comment: When downvoting, why not provide a comment at the same time? In this case, we have a new poster who perhaps needs to learn how best to phrase a question? @tohaz, I suspect this smells like homework firstly which isn't usually welcome unless you can show what you've tried so far. In fact, in general, you should always describe what steps you've taken and indicate the specific problem you have. In your question, you've put up a puzzle and asked someone to solve it. The response is always going to be "why should I?"

Comment: How is this base-independent? 17301 == 0x4395, but 7301 != 0x395.

Comment: i have an ugly function that iterates and uses % to truncate. haven't found better solution. sorry if it looks like homework :(

Comment: @tohaz Even if you have 'an ugly function', post it. Anything that shows that you've actually thought about the matter before asking others to help you is a LOT better than just throwing out the question.

Comment: @ATaylor posted it, i'll remember your recomendations in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit of a workaround, but it should do what you want (though I fail to see why you want it)

Anyway, first things first, you need to determine, which digit IS the leftmost digit.

For this, you need to know the base (you do know it, right?)
Once you know the left most digit, you need to substract this exact digit with it's position multiple by the base...and you're done.

Here's a code fragment on how this could be done. Untested though.

```
int truncate_left(int val, int base) {    
    int Multiplier = 1, LeftDigit = val;
    while(LeftDigit > base) {
        LeftDigit /= base;
        Multiplier *= base;
    }
    return val - (LeftDigit * Multiplier);
}
```

To deal with negative numbers as well, we need to add a little extra.

```
int truncate_left(int val, int base) {
    bool isNegative = (val < 0);
    int Multiplier = 1, LeftDigit = val;
    if(isNegative) LeftDigit *= -1;
    while(LeftDigit > base) {
        LeftDigit /= base;
        Multiplier *= base;
    }
    if(isNegative) LeftDigit *= -1;
    return val - (LeftDigit * Multiplier);
}
```

The `isNegative` flag will remember, if the number was negative to begin with and exists for our convenience (we could also check against `val < 0` two times). It turns `LeftDigit` into positive (it's 'absolute value', determines the multiplier and then turns it back negative.

Since `val` is negative and we subtract another negative value from it (-LeftDigit * Multiplier), it amounts to `+`, leading to the correct result with the sign preserved.

Comment: @Dipto I haven't really tested it (which is why I said 'Untested'). What output are you getting?

Comment: `p=truncate_left(17895,10);printf("%d\n",p);` is printing `-28105`

Comment: @Dipto It's something simple, I'm sure...lemme check that. And thanks for the heads up.

Comment: got it. return `val - (LeftDigit * Multiplier)`

Comment: @Dipto ...and there I was looking for a complicated answer. I'll edit it again. Thank you very much.

Comment: this is a nice way to do it, though it uses iterations too. thank you!

Comment: @tohaz I don't think you're ever going to get this done without the use of a mathematical function or iteration, simply because a number will always start at the least significant digit for a computer. Oh and you're very welcome :)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why @MM deleted his almost-there answer, but here's the corrected version of it:

```
int truncate_left(int x)
{
    int c = (int)log10(x);
    while (x > pow(10,c)) x -= pow(10,c);
    return x;
}
```

If use of math.h and -lm is a problem, replace log10 and pow with these:

```
int mylog10(int val)
{
   if (val > 9) return 1 + mylog10(val/10);
   return 1;
}

int mypow(int val, int pwr)
{
    if (pwr > 0) return val * mypow(val, pwr-1);
    return val;
}
```

Comment: OP says no math libraries?

Comment: @Koushik I don't think <math.h> is really a math library. It's a plain old C++ math function.

Comment: @ATaylor: Just change `val/10` to `val/16` or `val/2` to achieve `log16` or `log2`.

Answer (score 3):

If strings aren't cheating:

```
int truncate_left(int i) {
    return std::stoi(std::to_string(i).substr(1));
}
```

Comment: considered this, but there should be some faster ways. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've just wrote it:

```
int truncate_left(int x)
{
  int c = (int)log10(x);   // c: digits - 1
  int p = pow(10,c);       // p: 10 ^ c
  int k = x / p;           // k: leftmost non-zero digit
  return x - k * p;
}
```

*Note: `x` shall be greater that zero.*

Comment: This doesn't work for, for example, x==20002, which returns 10002. Instead... `while (x > pow((10,(int)log10(x))) x -= pow(10,(int)log10(x)); return x;`

Answer (score 2):

There's no quick way. You have to write 17301 as 10000 + 7301. It's then obvious that truncate_left returns the 7301 part. That leaves figuring out the 10000 part, which you can nick from the "print a number" code examples.

Answer (score 1):

Check this one too,

```
unsigned int tru(unsigned int a)
{
unsigned int b = a,c=0;

while(b!=0)
{
 c++;
 b /=10;
}

cout<<"length: "<<c<<endl;

int mul= 1;
c--;

while(c)
{
 mul *= 10;
 c--;
}

cout<<"mul is "<<mul<<endl;

return a%mul;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unsigned truncate_left_aux(unsigned n, unsigned sum, unsigned base){
    unsigned nn;
    return (0==(nn=n/10))? sum : truncate_left_aux(nn, sum + (n % 10) * base, 10*base);
}

unsigned truncate_left(unsigned n){
    truncate_left_aux(n, 0, 1);
}
```